# Why was the primary for the NY-3 district canceled, allowing George Santos to run as a Republican uncontested?

Tags: united-states, house-of-representatives, republican-primary, new-york

According to [Ballotpedia](https://ballotpedia.org/New_York%27s_3rd_Congressional_District_election,_2022_(August_23_Republican_primary)):

> The Republican primary election was canceled. George Devolder-Santos advanced from the Republican primary for U.S. House New York District 3.

Why was it canceled? Did no one else run in the primary?

Comment: Out of curiosity.  OK, no opponent in primary.  Got it.  But who was the lazy schmuck Dem opponent who didn't do any research on this loser?   Oh, that closet?  No skeletons in it, no sirree.  I get that the local opponent may themselves lack experience.  And that a small district is of limited interest to the national Dems.  Still, every seat counts:  how did the Dems miss this???

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica [The North Shore Leader, a local newspaper, caught him](https://www.theleaderonline.com/single-post/the-leader-told-you-so-us-rep-elect-george-santos-is-a-fraud-and-wanted-criminal) but nobody paid attention.

Comment: Some more about that huge big honking miss:  https://www.outsidethebeltway.com/how-misinformation-spreads/  (newspapers are understaffed and tend to clone each other) and https://www.vanityfair.com/news/2022/12/house-republicans-george-santos-democrats-ethics/amp an opposition research firm was paid $22K by the Dem candidate and either straight out missed it or was paid more to provide good soundbites on the culture wars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look closer at that section it lists the opponents in the election and in several cases it shows one that is listed as did not qualify for the ballot. In this case however there was no one opposing him which meant there was no need for a primary.